# Swing. Default keybindings in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, hotkeys

Now I working on a C IDE. As it's main theme is Motif, and my problem is how to add default KeyStroke(Ctrl + C - copy, Ctrl + V - paste) to `JTextPane`. In Motif L&F, `JTextPane` doesn't react on these KeyStrokes. How to make it perform the desired actions on these keys.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Meaning: if you have code that isn't working - past a minimal example of that code. There could be all kinds of things that you got wrong here.

Comment: *"JTextPane don't react on these keystorkes."* Thanks for telling us that. .. Do you have a question?

Comment: Well, you have to *implement* desired keystrokes.

Comment: @zlakad How to do this?

Comment: @zlakad, `you have to be familiar to event handlers.` - you should not be using an event handler for this. You should be using `Key Bindings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
JTextPane.setKeymap(
  JtextPane.getKeymap().addActionForKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK,DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to understand is that the KeyStrokes Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V are already catched by the JTextPane, so your listener will never be notified.

The fastest way to get notified is to register to this action via:

```
myJTextPane.getActionMap().put(DefaultEditorKit.copyAction, myCopyAction);
//and
myJTextPane.getActionMap().put(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction, myPasteAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Motif L&F, JTextPane doesn't react on these KeyStrokes. How to make it perform the desired actions on these keys.

You need to add your own `Key Bindings` to bind an `Action` to a `KeyStroke`.

Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a program to list the existing bindings for any Swing component for a given LAF.

It then shows how to share an `Action` with a different `KeyStroke`:

```
 KeyStroke existingKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
 KeyStroke addedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z");
 InputMap im = component.getInputMap(...);
 im.put(addedKeyStroke, im.get(existingKeyStroke));
```

Or add a binding to an `Action` with a `KeyStroke`:

```
 KeyStroke addedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z");
 InputMap im = component.getInputMap(...);
 im.put(addedKeyStroke, "caret-end-word");
```

I'll let you run the program to get the existing KeyStroke to use or the "action name" to use.

The above examples show how to change the binding for a single component. The link will also show how you can do it all JTextPanes by accessing the `InputMap` shared by all the text panes.

```
InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
```